# Automatic calculation from input fields

Tags: javascript, html

I want to construct some input forms that can calculate automatically. Provide below is my input forms.

```js
var form = document.forms.myform,
        pv1 = form.pv1,
        pv2 = form.pv2,
        output = form.pvtotal;

    window.calculate = function () {
        var p1 = parseInt(pv1.value, 10) || 0,
            p2 = parseFloat(pv2.value) || 0;
        output.value = (p1 + p2).toFixed(2);
    };
```

```css
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  color: black;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=number]{
    width: 50px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<form action="" name="myform" onkeyup="calculate()">
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
      <th colspan="3">PREV DAY STOCK</th>
      <th colspan="3">CULL</th>
      <th colspan="3">MORTALITY</th>
      <th colspan="3">CURRENT STOCK</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>M</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>M</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>M</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>M</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="pv1"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="pv2"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="pvtotal"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
    <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
    <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
    <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
    <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
    <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" readonly></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

As you can see and try, i just provide the sum for previous stock. The main problem is *I want all the column be automatic calculated except for the CURRENT STOCK column* which i want this column calculated by:

(**PREVIOUS STOCK - CULL - MORTALITY** = CURRENT STOCK

Then, the other problem whenever i add one row below, all the script did not function anymore. I don't know why. I hope you guys can help me through this.

Below is my expected output:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  color: black;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=number]{
    width: 50px;
}

div.scrollmenu {
  overflow: auto;
}

h4 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

```html
<form action="dailyprod_action.php" method="post" name="myform" onkeyup="calculate()">
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
      <th colspan="3">PREV DAY STOCK</th>
      <th colspan="3">CULL</th>
      <th colspan="3">MORTALITY</th>
      <th colspan="3">CURRENT STOCK</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>M</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>M</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>M</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>M</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="1000"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="1000"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="2000"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="200"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="200" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="400"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="200"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="200"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="400"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="600" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="600" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="1200" readonly></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="2000"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="2000"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="4000"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="400"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="400" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="800"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="400"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="400"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="800"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="1700" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="1700" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="" value="3400" readonly></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: do you need the solution to be in pure JS or jQuery?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph I'm more comfortable with JS

Comment: where do you display result? also, is it a row wise sum or column wise?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph The result is just like from the coding above. It's more likely a row wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop my sample script and try

```js
$("#pds_v1").keyup(function(){
 var pds_v1 = $("#pds_v1").val();
 var pds_v2 = $("#pds_v2").val();
 var total= parseInt(pds_v2) + parseInt(pds_v1);
 $("#pds_sum").val(total);
});

$("#pds_v2").keyup(function(){
 var pds_v1 = $("#pds_v1").val();
 var pds_v2 = $("#pds_v2").val();
 var total= parseInt(pds_v2) + parseInt(pds_v1);
 $("#pds_sum").val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="number" name="" id="pds_v1"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="" id="pds_v2"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="" id="pds_sum"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Let's say that my form have 6 inputs to auto calculated,  so that means I need to add 4 more function to your script?

Comment: Yes for now you try to get solutions adding 4 more functions then you can change them to make use of one function which will perform dynamically using for loop

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use JQuery as that will make your life easier, also there's not much difference between Javascript and JQuery syntax, so it'll be easy for you to learn if you know Javascript.

I moved your `onkeyup` event listener to the `tr` tag so you'll be able to do `calculate()` on every row. I also added `this` parameter on the `calculate()` function to get the element that fired that function and get all child from that element to change the `output` field of that row (the one that fired `calculate()` function).

Try this code below (this is only inputs for **Previous Stock**):

```js
function calculate(elem) {
  pv1 = $(elem).children()[0].children;
  pv2 = $(elem).children()[1].children;
  out = $(elem).children()[2].children;

  var p1 = parseInt($(pv1).val(), 10) || 0;
  var p2 = parseFloat($(pv2).val()) || 0;
  $(out).val((p1 * p2).toFixed(2));
}

$('#add_field').click(function() {
  $('#table_body').append(`
    <tr onkeyup="calculate(this)" onchange="calculate(this)">
        <td><input type="number" name="pv1" id="pv1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="pv2" id="pv2"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="pvtotal" id="output"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="" readonly></td>
    </tr>
  `)
})

$('#remove_field').click(function() {
  var len = ($('#table_body').children()).length - 1;
  $('#table_body').children()[len].remove();
})
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  color: black;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=number] {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" name="myform">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">PREV DAY STOCK</th>
        <th colspan="3">CULL</th>
        <th colspan="3">MORTALITY</th>
        <th colspan="3">CURRENT STOCK</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>M</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>M</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>M</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>M</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_body">
      <!-- I'm moving your event listener to the <tr> tag -->
      <tr onkeyup="calculate(this)" onchange="calculate(this)">
        <td><input type="number" name="pv1" id="pv1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="pv2" id="pv2"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="pvtotal" id="output"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="" readonly></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
<button type="button" id="add_field">Add Field</button>
<button type="button" id="remove_field">Remove Field</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the great work! Been amazed with your coding. But just want to ask, what if the rows is populated by list of id from another table? Still the coding above can be applied?

Comment: @ZulMajdi I'm afraid you can't use that code, it's only for inputs, if you're getting a data from another table/database, you need to add another extra lines or maybe a new function to get the data, process the calculation, then set the value into this table